# What is the difference between iterator_category and iterator_concept?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++20, std-ranges, iterator-traits

C++20 brings a more powerful [iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) system, one of them is to introduce `iterator_concept` on the basis of `iterator_category`.

I found that the `iterator_concept` and `iterator_category` of many iterators in C++20 are inconsistent. Take the most famous `iota_view` as an [example](https://godbolt.org/z/fh1W3xond):

```
using R = decltype(views::iota(0));
static_assert(random_access_range<R>);

using I = ranges::iterator_t<R>;
static_assert(same_as<typename I::iterator_category, input_iterator_tag>);
static_assert(same_as<typename I::iterator_concept,  random_access_iterator_tag>);
```

Although `R` models `random_access_range`, the `iterator_category` of its iterator is just an `input_iterator_tag`, which is inconsistent with the `iterator_concept`.

Why does C++20 introduce `iterator_concept`? What is its purpose? If I implement my own iterator, how do I define `iterator_concept` and `iterator_category` correctly? Does `iterator_category` still have a meaning in C++20?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are differences between the C++17 (C++98) iterator model and the C++20 Ranges iterator model that are not backwards compatible. The two big ones are:

1. The C++98 model requires that forward iterators have a `reference` that is either `value_type&` or `value_type const&`.
2. The C++98 model does not allow for `contiguous` iterators. The strongest category was `random_access`.

The consequence of (1) is pretty significant - it means that if you have an iterator that returns a prvalue (whether proxy reference or not), it can never be stronger than an input iterator. So, `views::iota(1, 10)`, despite easily being able to support random access, is only, at best, a C++98 input range.

However, you can't just... remove this requirement. Existing code that assumes C++98 iterators and uses `iterator_category` to make judgements is perfectly within its rights to assume that if `iterator_category` is, say, `bidirectional_iterator_tag`, that its `reference` is some kind of lvalue reference to `value_type`.

What `iterator_concept` does is add a new C++20 layer that allows an iterator to both advertise its C++98/17 category and, distinctly, advertise its C++20 category. So going back to the `iota_view<int, int>` example, that view's iterator has `iterator_category` set to `input_iterator_tag` (because the `reference` is a prvalue and so it does not satisfy the old requirements for even forward) but its `iterator_concept` is set to `random_access_iterator_tag` (because once we drop that restriction, we can easily support all the random access restrictions).

In [[iterator.concepts.general]](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.concepts.general), we have this magic function `ITER_CONCEPT(I)` which helps us figure out what tag to use in C++20.

The issue with (2) is that it was hard to just add a new `contiguous_iterator_tag` before due to the way that various C++98/17 code would check for that tag (lots of code might check for exactly `random_access_iterator_tag`). The `iterator_concept` approach avoids this problem by also introducing concepts that directly check the right thing for you (i.e. the [`random_access_iterator`](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.concept.random.access) concept checks that `ITER_CONCEPT(I)` derives from `random_access_iterator_tag`, not that it simply is that).

---

Guidelines:

- If you're *using* an iterator in C++17, use `std::iterator_traits<I>::iterator_category`.
- If you're *using* an iterator in C++20, use the `std::meow_iterator` concepts
- If you're *writing* an iterator in C++17, add the `iterator_category` alias and make sure you follow the forward iterator/reference restriction (or... don't, but it's on you)
- If you're *writing* an iterator in C++20, follow the guidance in [P2259](https://wg21.link/p2259) which has a good description of the problem and how and when to provide the `iterator_category` and `iterator_concept` type aliases.

Comment: +100. Thanks, Barry. In addition, `iterator_concept` and `iterator_category` seem to be inconsistent with whether the iterator is `const`. For example, in [range.transform#iterator-1.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.transform#iterator-1.1), the `iterator_concept` of `transform_view`'s iterator is defined according to the original `V`, but `iterator_category` is based on `Base` (maybe `const V` or `V`). Would you like to explain a little bit about this inconsistency?

Comment: @康桓瑋 It's inconsistent yeah, but I don't think it makes a huge difference (I don't know that the library cares about the case where like... `V` is random access but `V const` is forward. Like... why?) More typically, `V` is random access but `V const` isn't even a range, in which case the distinction wouldn't matter as much.

Comment: I recall some musings about making `V const` input if you need to cache in `begin` but can't because of `const`.

Comment: @T.C. But if `V` does not provide a `begin() const` function, `transform_view::iterator<const>` will not be instantiated because of the constraints of `transform_view::begin() const`. I still can't understand the problems that `const` can cause here.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Please stop using sock puppet accounts to give Barry reputation.  It will go to his head.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont wat

Comment: @barry they upvoted you 100 times!  "+100":  I mean, show some restraint.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont lol. No restraint necessary :-)

Comment: This is [LWG3555](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#3555).