# Creating an Iterator with C++20 Concepts for custom container

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

> C++20 introduces concepts, a smart way to put constraints on the types a
> template function or class can take in.
>
> While iterator categories and properties remain the same, what changes is how you enforce them:
> with tags until C++17, with concepts since C++20. For example, instead of the std::forward_iterator_tag tag
> you would mark your iterator with the std::forward_iterator concept.
>
> The same thing applies to all iterator properties.
> For example, a Forward Iterator must be std::incrementable.
> This new mechanism helps in getting better iterator definitions and makes errors from the compiler
> much more readable.

This piece of text it's taken from this article:
https://www.internalpointers.com/post/writing-custom-iterators-modern-cpp

But the author didn't upgrade the content on how to make a custom iterator on C++20 with concepts, it remains the <= C++17 tags version.

Can someone make an example on how to write a custom iterator for a custom container in a C++20 version with the concept features?

Comment: I would say it is more the functions using iterators which might be updated to use concept with overload instead of tag dispatching (for example [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) will have `template <typename It> requires(random_access_iterator<It>) auto do_distance(It first, It last)`)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By and large, the C++20 way of defining iterators does away with explicitly tagging the type, and instead relies on concepts to just check that a given type happens to respect the iterator category's requirements.

This means that you can now safely duck-type your way to victory while supporting clean overload resolution and error messages:

```
struct my_iterator {
  // No need for tagging or anything special, just implement the required interface.
};
```

If you want to ensure that a given type fulfills the requirements of a certain iterator category, you `static_assert` the concept on that type:

```
#include <iterator>

static_assert(std::forward_iterator<my_iterator>);
```

Enforcing that a function only accepts a certain iterator category is done by using the concept in your template arguments.

```
#include <iterator>

template<std::forward_iterator Ite, std::sentinel_for<Ite> Sen>
void my_algorithm(Ite begin, Sen end) {
 // ...
}
```

[`std::sentinel_for<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/sentinel_for) is now used for the end iterator instead of using `Ite` twice. It allows to optionally use a separate type for the end iterator, which is sometimes convenient, especially for input iterators.

For example:

```
struct end_of_stream_t {};
constexpr end_of_stream_t end_of_stream{};

struct my_input_iterator {
  // N.B. Not a complete implementation, just demonstrating sentinels.
  some_stream_type* data_stream;

  bool operator==(end_of_stream_t) const { return data_stream->empty(); }
};

template<std::input_iterator Ite, std::sentinel_for<Ite> Sen>
void my_algorithm(Ite begin, Sen end) {
  while(begin != end) {
    //...
  }
}

void foo(some_stream_type& stream) {
  my_algorithm(my_input_iterator{&stream}, end_of_stream);
}
```

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks, I'm legit not sure what `iterator_concept` actually accomplishes, as it doesn't check anything by itself until the type is used as an iterator. In my mind, it should always be accompanied by the static_assert, which makes it immediately redudant. Am I missing something here? **Edit**: The answer is probably, as usual, templates.

Comment: Not as useful as I thought, my bad. [Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67606563/2752075) it's only needed when the desired concept is different from old-school iterator category, since they have slightly different requirements.

Comment: Hey Frank, thanks for your detailed answer. I get the point on what you've wrote.
But I am struggling with the concept on having the iterator inside my class (ah, this is for practice to create my own container), and following the article guidelines, my answer was more focused on how to replace the code provided there with the C++20 concepts.

I am just a little bit stuck there with the concepts syntax instead of the tags one.

Could you modify your example based on the article one with the concept? Or better, just add the code for the C++20? 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: @AlexVergara The thing is, as I said: there aren't any differences, and that's what the answer to the question you asked is. However, there might be something unusual about the code you are converting that's tripping you up, but we can't tell from here. You should ask a question containing a simplified version of code you want to convert, and your attempt at a conversion (exhibiting the same challenges you are facing). Then someone can figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: @AlexVergara In fact, in my experience, 80% of the time, I figure what I'm doing wrong while writing the simplified version of my problem and end up never posting my question to the site.

Comment: You're right. And I appreciated your response. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

All other answers gave you an idea on how to do it in C++20, and as they mentioned, nothing has really changed since C++17 besides using compiler assertion checks for the validity of the iterators. Anyway, here is the C++20 version of a *forward_iterator*. In this examples only the required operators are implemented, and for the sake of the illustration a custom constructor was added.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template <typename T>
class Integers {
public:
    struct Iterator {
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using element_type = T; // element_type is a reserved name that must be used in the definition
    using pointer = element_type *;
    using reference = element_type &;

    private:
        pointer ptr, start, sentinel;
        static_assert(std::sentinel_for<decltype(sentinel), decltype(ptr)>);
    public:
        // Default constructor is required to pass forward_iterator assertion
        Iterator() { throw std::runtime_error("Not implemented"); }
        Iterator(pointer p, pointer s) : ptr(p), start(p), sentinel(s) {}
        reference operator*() const { return *ptr; }
        auto &operator++() { ptr++; return *this; }
        auto operator++(int) { auto tmp = *this; ++(*this); return tmp; }
        auto operator<=>(const Iterator &) const = default; // three-way comparison C++20
        auto begin() {return start;}
        auto end() {return sentinel;}
    };

    auto begin() { return iter.begin(); }
    auto end() { return iter.end(); }
    Integers() {
        T j = 1;
        for(auto i = begin(); i != end(); ++i)
            *i = j++;
    }
private:
    T m_data[5];
    static_assert(std::forward_iterator<Iterator>);
    Iterator iter = Iterator(m_data, std::end(m_data));
};

template <typename T>
void print(Integers<T>& integers) {
    bool firstIteration = true;
    for (auto i : integers) {
        if (firstIteration) {
            firstIteration = false;
        } else {
            std::cout << " ";
        }
        std::cout << i;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Integers<int> container;
    static_assert(std::forward_iterator<decltype(container.begin())>);
    print(container);
    std::fill(container.begin(), container.end(), 3);
    print(container);
}
```

Here you can check the code working as expected https://godbolt.org/z/o6ad3Knc7

And anyway, the output of the code should be:

```
1 2 3 4 5
3 3 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting this here as much for my own future benefit.
A minimal contiguous iterator, as you go farther down the tree of iterators, less and less of this becomes required, but you can't have a contiguous without at least this much

```
#include <iterator>

template<typename T>
struct Iterator {
  using iterator_concept [[maybe_unused]] = std::contiguous_iterator_tag;
  using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
  using element_type = T;
  using pointer = element_type *;
  using reference = element_type &;

  Iterator() = default;
  Iterator(pointer p) { _ptr = p; }

  reference operator*() const { return *_ptr; }
  pointer operator->() const { return _ptr; }

  Iterator &operator++() {
    _ptr++;
    return *this;
  }
  Iterator operator++(int) {
    Iterator tmp = *this;
    ++(*this);
    return tmp;
  }
  Iterator &operator+=(int i) {
    _ptr += i;
    return *this;
  }
  Iterator operator+(const difference_type other) const { return _ptr + other; }
  friend Iterator operator+(const difference_type value,
                            const Iterator &other) {
    return other + value;
  }

  Iterator &operator--() {
    _ptr--;
    return *this;
  }
  Iterator operator--(int) {
    Iterator tmp = *this;
    --(*this);
    return tmp;
  }
  Iterator &operator-=(int i) {
    _ptr -= i;
    return *this;
  }
  difference_type operator-(const Iterator &other) const {
    return _ptr - other._ptr;
  }
  Iterator operator-(const difference_type other) const { return _ptr - other; }
  friend Iterator operator-(const difference_type value,
                            const Iterator &other) {
    return other - value;
  }

  reference operator[](difference_type idx) const { return _ptr[idx]; }

  auto operator<=>(const Iterator &) const = default;

private:
  pointer _ptr;
};

int main() {
  static_assert(std::contiguous_iterator<Iterator<char>>);

  return 0;
}
```