How to use C++20's concept to check my custom iterator implementation is complete
Let's say I want to implement my own collection type like below:
#define ARR_SIZE 20

class IntegersCollection {
public:
  class Iterator {
  public:
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type = int;
    using pointer = value_type *;
    using reference = value_type &;

    Iterator(pointer ptr) : m_ptr(ptr) {}

    reference operator*() const { return *m_ptr; }
    pointer operator->() { return m_ptr; }
    Iterator &operator++() {
      m_ptr++;
      return *this;
    }
    Iterator operator++(int) {
      Iterator tmp = *this;
      ++(*this);
      return tmp;
    }
    friend bool operator==(const Iterator &a, const Iterator &b) {
      return a.m_ptr == b.m_ptr;
    };
    friend bool operator!=(const Iterator &a, const Iterator &b) {
      return a.m_ptr != b.m_ptr;
    };

  private:
    pointer m_ptr;
  };

  Iterator begin() { return Iterator(&m_data[0]); }
  Iterator end() { return Iterator(&m_data[ARR_SIZE]); }

private:
  int m_data[ARR_SIZE];
};

The problem is, there are many ways users can use a collection type/container type with an iterator. I am not sure if I already implemented all the needed member methods/fields that are needed by a complete and proper iterator.
C++20 introduced the Concept feature, and there are some iterator-related concepts like this one. I am thinking:
Is there something like an "iterator concept" which clearly defines what member methods/fields a particular type of iterator (say forward iterator) should have? I am imagining some thing like below:
template <typename T>
concept is_shape = requires(T v) {
  { v.area() } -> std::floating_point;
};

class Circle {
private:
  double r;
public:
  Circle(double r) { this->r = r; }
  double area() { return r * r * std::numbers::pi_v<float>; };
};

template <is_shape T> float getVolume(T &shape, float height) {
  return shape.area() * height;
}

Circle my_circle(3);
std::cout << getVolume(my_circle, 7.2) << "\n";

We can have an is_shape concept that mandates what all "shapes" should behave, do we have something for iterators, so that if i miss some methods/fields, the C++ can fail me immediately, instead of delaying the failure to a while later, when a real user uses my iterator in a particular way and discovers that my iterator actually misses some important features?

This question is similar to: How to correctly implement custom iterators and const_iterators?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Anerdw the question you shared is from 2013, C++20 introduced Concept, as we do have some iterator-related concept here, I believe this question will have some new answers.

These are all the requirements depending on the iterator category.  The link is to the base iterator and there are links to the other categories in there: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Iterator

@NathanOliver i believe this is what we have pre-C++20.

Is this any better? https://stackoverflow.com/q/72405122

As the question is currently worded, the answer seems to be just replacing is_shape in your second snippet with std::random_access_iterator you found. I fail to understand what you are actually asking.

@WeijunZhou can you shared some code snippet to demonstrate your idea. i have no idea how such replace can work and make it a part of the iterator.

What do you mean by "part of the iterator"? If you want to ensure your iterator satisfies the concept, just add a static_assert(std::random_access_iterator<Iterator>); after the iterator class definiton. If you need a concept that singles out classes with a nested Iterator type that satisfies the concept, just do template<T> concept HasValidIterator<T>=std::random_access_iterator<typename T::Iterator>;

compilers now complains Because 'IntegersCollection::Iterator' does not satisfy 'forward_iterator', what should be changed to make it work then?

You need to read the full message, it will tell you which subconcept it fails. If the message is truncated, try to tune flags like -fconcepts-diagnostics-depth or whatever flag your compiler provides

@WeijunZhou i did a bit more test, i believe no this is not the correct approach. if you know how to make it work, free feel to post a complete answer, i will point out at that time regarding what goes wrong.

I don't understand. The error message from concepts clearly points out that you are missing a default constructor. It cannot be clearer than that.

You asked how to use concepts to test whether your iterator implementation was complete, and you've been told the answer. Now you're asking for help understanding why your iterator implementation is not complete, which is a different question.

The iterator_category is the iterator class's claim, and it has to provide interface functions that support it. Every iterator category has a corresponding concept that checks those required functions, as well as the claimed category.


Is there something like an "iterator concept"

You already linked to the concept std::random_access_iterator, so presumably you know the answer is yes.
That page says it refines std::bidirectional_iterator ..., which itself refines std::forward_iterator ..., which in turn refines std::input_iterator, which ... etc.

... so that if i miss some methods/fields, the C++ can fail me immediately, instead of delaying the failure to a while later, when a real user uses my iterator in a particular way and discovers that my iterator actually misses some important features?

You haven't actually said which features you intend to support. That is, I don't know whether you were intending to implement a random access iterator (you're missing operator[]), or a bidirectional iterator (missing operator--), or what.
Once you pick the iterator concept you intend to implement, just writing eg.
static_assert(std::random_access_iterator<Iterator>);

(as already described in comments) is sufficient.
If the static assert fails, you have your answer: you haven't correctly implemented the concept. Now you need to read the error messages telling you why.
For example, if the compiler tells your it doesn't satisfy
concept semiregular = copyable<_Tp> && default_initializable<_Tp>;
                                       ^

that clearly means you need to add a default constructor (or a default value for your existing constructor argument).
It's because forward_iterator requires incrementable which requires regular which requires semiregular which requires default_initializable - all of which is described in both the error message and the documentation you already linked.

Do you have a working version of the collection class definition with concept requirements applied and met?

@D.J.Elkind look into your std implementation. Every std collection has a working implementation.

@Red.Wave okay, pls copy and paste your std's implementation then. talk is cheap.

So far we have "how to check X?" Then "how to fix Y when the check fails?" And now "how to check Z instead?" This is supposed to be a question (singular) and answer format, not a discussion board.

Work load belongs the OP. If you can't follow the available header only library in front of you, you're not ready for advanced stuff you're trying.

@Red.Wave this is why SO is toxic, but fine, I asked some LLMs, and everything working now. Happy lecturing other users on SO!

Good luck relying on LLMs if nobody else is writing the material to train them, I guess.
