# Are c++20 iterators "convertible" to LegacyIterators?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++20, c++-concepts, legacy

As I understand it, before C++20 iterators were just a concept defined by the standard. Now in C++20 they are real language concepts which are checked at compile time. I'm wondering if I'm safe to assume that I can consume a C++20 iterator in my API and pass it to any pre-C++20  API without it breaking:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:17,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:17,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:17,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:17),source:%27%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Cconcepts%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%0Aauto+write_string(std::input_iterator+auto+it)+-%3E+void+%7B%0A%0A++++std::string+ret+%3D+%22Danger%22%3B%0A++++std::copy(ret.begin(),+ret.end(),+it)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++std::string+str+%3D+%22Austin+is+my+middle+name%22%3B%0A++++write_string(str.begin())%3B%0A++++printf(%22%25.*s%5Cn%22,+(int)str.size(),+str.data())%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Os%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <string>
#include <concepts>
#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>

auto write_string(std::input_iterator auto it) -> void { // <-- C++20 iterator

    std::string ret = "Danger";
    std::copy(ret.begin(), ret.end(), it); // <-- requires LegacyInputIterator
}

int main()
{
    std::string str = "Austin is my middle name";
    write_string(str.begin());
    printf("%.*s\n", (int)str.size(), str.data());
}
```

Comment: @康桓瑋 What then is the prefered way to do just what I wrote? Forward the underlying iterator concept used by std::copy to my API?

Comment: Concepts are a fancy way of checking if the type matches requirements. The actual types are still the same. `decltype(it)` and `decltype(str.begin())` will yield the same type (ignoring the value categories). They are not "convertible", they are the same thing.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen True should have used an input iterator from a differnt kind of entity, but I couldn't think of one (please consider editing the question if you have a more general example). The point is that this API would accept all iterators that satisfy the input_iterator category of c++20. How would I constrain it to the iterators used by std::copy to have a more narrow fit?

Comment: @康桓瑋 This source seems to indicate however that when I'm using c++20 I should in fact use the said concepts to constrain iterators (see guidelines)...

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is here. If you pass a wrong iterator, it won't compile anyway (maybe with a bit more cryptic error message). `std::vector<int> v{}; write_string(v.begin());` won't compile with or without concepts. You could accept `std::string::iterator` as argument, but that prevents `std::vector<char>::iterator` from being passed. If you want a concept that checks if this specific `copy` can be called, you can devise your own concept that checks if the type is `std::output_iterator` and `std::is_same_v<*it, char>`. But that's a bit over the top IMO.

Answer (score 3):

`std::copy` requires that the type of the third parameter must meet the requirements of *LegacyOutputIterator*, that is, it must support the writing operation, which is not guaranteed by `std::input_iterator`.

In C++20, the corresponding concept is `std::output_iterator`, so you can redeclare `write_string` as

```
void write_string(std::output_iterator<const char&> auto it) {
  std::string ret = "Danger";
  std::copy(ret.begin(), ret.end(), it);
}
```

This guarantees that the type of `it` satisfies the syntax requirements for output iterators written to `char`.

(Although the C++20 iterator system is [very different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67606563/what-is-the-difference-between-iterator-category-and-iterator-concept-in-c20) from C++98/C++17, the requirements for output iterators are basically equivalent. so in your example, using `std::output_iterator` to check the requirement of *LegacyOutputIterator* is fine)

Answer (score 1):

No.

The old *LegacyInputIterator* concept also required `std::equality_comparable`, which is no longer required for `std::input_iterator`.

Therefore, a C++20 iterator type that's not `std::equality_comparable` is not a *LegacyInputIterator* and might break old API's.

`std::output_iterator` however is not required to be `std::equality_comparable`.

Comment: Where is it required that *LegacyIterator* is `equality_comparable`? Cppreference doesn't mention it for [*LegacyIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Iterator) and explicitly mentions that [*LegacyOutputIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/OutputIterator) needs not to be comparable.

Comment: @Bob__ Ah, right. It's kinda confusing that OP chose to talk about `std::input_iterator` for argument that should be *LegacyOutputIterator*. I'll take the liberty to edit the answer to change *LegacyIterator* to *LegacyInputIterator*