# Why is the std::iterator_traits::iterator_category for pointers not std::contiguous_iterator_tag?

Tags: c++, iterator, language-design, iterator-traits

> `iterator_traits` is specialized for pointers as
>
> ```cpp
> namespace std {
>   template<class T>
>     requires is_object_v<T>
>   struct iterator_traits<T*> {
>     using iterator_concept  = contiguous_iterator_tag;
>     using iterator_category = random_access_iterator_tag;
>     using value_type        = remove_cv_t<T>;
>     using difference_type   = ptrdiff_t;
>     using pointer           = T*;
>     using reference         = T&;
>   };
> }
> ```

- [[iterator.traits] p5](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.traits#5)

How come only the `iterator_concept` but not the `iterator_category` for pointers is `std::contiguous_iterator_tag`.
To my knowledge, pointers are contiguous iterators in every sense.

Is this an oversight, or is there a practical reason for this?

Comment: Backwards-compatibility with pre-C++20 code that doesn't know about `contiguous_iterator_tag` (and checks iterator tags for exact match instead of inheritance): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67606563/what-is-the-difference-between-iterator-category-and-iterator-concept-in-c20

Comment: @user17732522 you mean if it checked the category with `std::is_same_v`? I was thinking that it wouldn't be a breaking change if tag dispatch was used, but you seem to be onto something here.

Comment: Yes, that's probably what most code naively does e.g. in a `std::enable_if`.